# Ruby set max in queryset results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
vals = Value.select('date, name, info, price').order(:date, :name, :info)
```

And what I need to do right now:
Is to set parameter age as maximum of all ages.
I mean if I have 2 records with price`15` and `23`, they both should have `price=23`

I can think of finding max and iterating through `vals` queryset object and setting it every object. 
Like this: (not exact syntax just for example)
`vals.each do |val| val.price = vals.maximum(:price) end`

Is there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Value.update_all(price: Value.maximum(:price))
```

I don't get exactly what you want to do but this one set all row's price to the max and I think your approach could be something like this.

You could even apply some conditions before the `update_all`.

```
Value.where(a: 5, b: 7).update_all(price: Value.maximum(:price))
```